# Moodle3.5::Course modules for a course

Tags: php, moodle

Get course modules for a course:

I was trying to get course modules for current courseid. Tried to pull out the array values with print_r and var_dump, not with exact string conversion.

I was looking for module instance or module id and module name (modname) from the array output.

I want the course modules from the course, displays coursename, modules on a custom page.

```
global $DB;
$course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $courseid));
$info = get_fast_modinfo($course);
print_r($info);
//var_dump($info);
```

Comment: Okay. So what's the question?

Comment: I want to extract module id and module name from $info.

Comment: Okay, so what's in `$info`?

Comment: The output is in the format of array, objects. Its too lengthy. Could I post the output here

Comment: Or a pastebin or whatever, but it's kind of hard to tell you how to access your datastructures if you don't let us know what your datastructures are ;)

Comment: Loek - Hope you got the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you need is as follows:

```
$modinfo = get_fast_modinfo($courseid);
foreach ($modinfo->get_cms() as $cminfo) {
    echo $cminfo->id.' ('.$cminfo->instance.'): '.$cminfo->get_formatted_name().'<br>';
}
```

Have a look at lib/modinfolib.php, class course_modinfo for details of the functions you can call on the object returned by get_fast_modinfo(). Look at the cm_info class in the same file for details for the object returned by get_cms() / get_cm($cmid).

Comment: I just ran this exact code against a Moodle site I have locally and I don't get any such errors. I can't think of a reason why $modinfo->get_cms() would include a null value in the array of results. Maybe add the line $cms = $modinfo->get_cms(), stick a breakpoint on it and examine it in your IDE (or, if you really don't have xdebug configured properly, just add a var_dump($cms) instead)

Comment: Spotted my typo - just fixing now.